# Get HTTP MP3 stream from every song

Tags: json, mp3, soundcloud

I need to get the direct URL from a SoundCloud MP3 file.

I normally used the following method:
Resolve the track URL to get the track id, e.g. using https://soundcloud.com/linkin_park/burn-it-down with

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/your/link/to/the/track&client_id=client_id
```

Then go for the stream_urls with

http://api.sndcdn.com/i1/tracks/track_id_here/streams?client_id=client_id

In most cases, the "http_128_mp3_url", the URL I need, is returned, which links directly to the MP3 of the song.

But in some cases, e.g. when you use https://soundcloud.com/dada-life/dada-life-september-2014-mix, only the rtmp or hls stream is returned, which I cannot convert to a file with PHP or JavaScript.

As seen on http://sounddrain.com/, there is a way to get the link for the MP3 file in this case too.

Sounddrain gives me this URL:

https://ec-media.sndcdn.com/KZ5qiLqZ0OSk.128.mp3?f10880d39085a94a0418a7ef69b03d522cd6dfee9399eeb9a522029c6df9ba3f0cf21c0c0d9baf9fe2d9aa920d344c36db47817ce450103d44677da7d832da82ef7609816e

Has someone an idea how to get the following URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate and discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455033/stream-url-of-soundcloud-track-where-streamble-is-false/29463185#29463185

Comment: @JAL I cannot use additional tools like rtmpdump or ffmpeg, so I need to rely on the URL system. The preview_url has only a part of the track and not the right key/value pair for the full one.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this is counter to the terms & conditions of the API. https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/terms-of-use#privacy Using the credentials of a different application is, well, not so nice either.

Comment: @nickf As an engineer at SoundCloud can you specify why the endpoint returns different values for different credentials?  How can we always return an MP3 URL (or is that against the TOS)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this specifically has to do with the type of client_id you pass into the API request.

```
HTTP GET: http://api.soundcloud.com/i1/tracks/167132129/streams?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]
```

Using a standard application client_id, I don't see the http link:

Response:

```
{
  "hls_mp3_128_url": "https://ec-hls-media.soundcloud.com/playlist/KZ5qiLqZ0OSk.128.mp3/playlist.m3u8?f10880d39085a94a0418a7e062b03d52bbdc0e179b82bde1d76ce7a51e4e690d4aa9adbb8e264aa259bfba6e1a3d52e8f8020eeb45fac9d9fbb175e4c35dbd26bdf59ac00d0f2cd80b7e7a685e9cd57c89622a7cc8b7266f4b7317b4",
  "rtmp_mp3_128_url": "rtmp://ec-rtmp-media.soundcloud.com/mp3:KZ5qiLqZ0OSk.128?9527d18f1063a01f059bf10590159adb10dea0996b8c0cdb674f9c282214839d8263f0608a1a3bbe02e4a0ffc5cf5bef80087ca63aa316e338f6cbba24b1493d8355aea84dc2e529757f72273e1fdfc9f88437c992e92845b3e3",
  "preview_mp3_128_url": "https://ec-preview-media.sndcdn.com/preview/0/90/KZ5qiLqZ0OSk.128.mp3?f10880d39085a94a0418a7e162b03d52e21adf826af17a391e1b741835259dfd645b4f9f979acc1e4d50dd281c2b93dca58d9e3bd086be0aed9c5ae0ae369364f50bd63ee4f1b167cc29b19cf3462f735b8f"
}
```

However, using the youtube-dl iPhone client_id, the http url is returned:

Response:

```
{
    "http_mp3_128_url": "https://ec-media.sndcdn.com/KZ5qiLqZ0OSk.128.mp3?f10880d39085a94a0418a7ef69b03d522cd6dfee9399eeb9a522029c69f0bd356988380857d739f55360e9ce802160a1ecf506cfa53f249070d96b19de5ac3234cdbd4201d",
    "hls_mp3_128_url": "https://ec-hls-media.soundcloud.com/playlist/KZ5qiLqZ0OSk.128.mp3/playlist.m3u8?f10880d39085a94a0418a7e062b03d52bbdc0e179b82bde1d76ce7a51e4e6e074a18d603fc2146725c4f70a8844d81268632e8339ce8b52aab8fcfbfd450330b409e8614da1996b8e4cd371f07c9eb0d5cc65ffbf60230336388b323",
    "rtmp_mp3_128_url": "rtmp://ec-rtmp-media.soundcloud.com/mp3:KZ5qiLqZ0OSk.128?9527d18f1063a01f059bf10590159adb10dea0996b8c0cdb674f9c28221b8a972788cc587dee254b285c2a0c9e5b57a79b4bd174401f92b31df0cf4260d9f3f6fe542e181d30b4e9314ac36e70737095ddb2b215bd98884660cb",
    "preview_mp3_128_url": "https://ec-preview-media.sndcdn.com/preview/0/90/KZ5qiLqZ0OSk.128.mp3?f10880d39085a94a0418a7e162b03d52e21adf826af17a391e1b7418352a94f7cbd4ec4b06d76ae6caf6f3cc29aed3f7b0922885d994c71a503c307cf86b653b3f6108990bebaae5a15efc74075285b13f23"
}
```

More information can be found in [this commit](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/commit/64bb5187f53caea0e6067434c95da60284eef2ea) and [this issue](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/1798) on the youtube-dl page.  I don't know exactly what the difference is between a regular client_id and an iPhone client_id, but I can clearly see the difference in what is returned by the API request.  It would appear that the iPhone client_id is the API key used by the SoundCloud iOS client to stream tracks in the app.

Answer (score 0):

soundcloud re-encodes all uploads to 128k mp3 for streaming playback. as long as you have streaming enabled and the track is public, all you should need is

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/TRACKID/stream?client_id=CLIENTID

Comment: As explained above, I need the link to the MP3 file. For the given song, this approach doesn't work.

Comment: then you can use a tool such as youtube-dl http://yt-dl.org.

$ youtube-dl -g https://soundcloud.com/user/track

-g option will return the resource you are looking for.

Comment: Might be an option, but I don't want to rely on other programs or services