# Soundcloud API playlist returns no tracks in certain cases

Tags: api, soundcloud

When trying to get the track details for a playlist using the /playlists endpoint, for certain playlists there are no tracks returned in the data.

**Sample of returned data**

```
"license":"all-rights-reserved",
"tracks":[],
"playlist_type":null,
"id":199987807,
```

So far all the playlists behaving this way contain a single track, but NOT all playlists with one track return no tracks.

Examples of no tracks returned:

http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/199987807?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/199987052?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoundCloud API keys have different access levels.  SoundCloud can restrict API access for certain artists and playlists based on the API key used to make the request.

As you can see, a standard developer API key cannot see the tracks from those playlists.

There is a way around this, although it breaks SoundCloud's terms of service.

Using a different API key, such as the key [youtube-dl uses](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/commit/64bb5187f53caea0e6067434c95da60284eef2ea) to get the MP3 link for specific tracks (which is presumably a Soundcloud master key), gives you access to this information.

Again, using someone else's API key violates SoundCloud's terms of service, and there is no guarantee this key will continue working.  This is just a workaround to the current restriction you're seeing.

Related discussion in two other questions: [Get HTTP MP3 stream from every song](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29914622/2415822) and [SoundCloud API returning 0 tracks despite user having tracks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33485387/2415822).